# Trouble accessing react navigation (v5) without the navigation prop / outside components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

In my react native project, I have an authContext file to manage user signup and login.

Once a user has signed up (or logged in) successfully, I want the relevant function in the context file to redirect the user to a homepage ('TrackList'). Because the context sits outside the react navigation container, I have been following the v5 react navigation docs for '[Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop)' which clearly states that  "you may use this approach outside of your React components". Here is my implementation, which I will try to keep to a minimum for readability.

AuthContext file looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import trackerApi from "../api/tracker"

import * as RootNavigation from '../RootNavigation'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [token, setToken] = useState(null)//token from express server indicates user signed in
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")

    const signup = async ({ email, password }) => {
        try {
            //returns JSON Web Token JWT and update state
            const response = await trackerApi.post("/signup", { email, password })
            setToken(response.data.token)
        } catch (err) {
            setErrorMessage("Something went wrong with sign up")
        }
        //after successful signup we redirect  
        RootNavigation.navigate('TrackList')
    }

    const signIn = ...

    const signOut = ...

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, signup, signIn, signOut, errorMessage }}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}

export default AuthContext
```

Then within my App.js I have:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';
import { AuthProvider } from "./src/context/AuthContext"
(...other relevant imports)

function TrackListFlow() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Signup">
     //**SCREEN I WANT TO REDIRECT TO: **
      <Stack.Screen name="TrackList" component={TrackListScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={TrackDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function MainFlow() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="TrackListFlow">
      <Tab.Screen name="TrackListFlow" component={TrackListFlow} />
      <Tab.Screen name="TrackCreate" component={TrackCreateScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginFlow" >
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginFlow" component={LoginFlow}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="MainFlow" component={MainFlow} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The login process works, and when using buttons WITHIN the navigation container, the react navigation process works fine. However, I can't seem to navigate to the screen outside the navigation container (ie from authcontext). When I do, I get the following error:

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"TrackList"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'TrackList'?

I must admit, that while I follow a lot of the react navigation docs and processes, I am a bit confused about this section so it's possible I'm taking the wrong approach entirely. Help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so it works fine if I instead navigate to MainFlow - ie RootNavigation.navigate('MainFlow'), which has 'TrackList' as it's initial screen. So this sortof works, but I don't understand why I can't navigate directly to the screen I want (TrackList) as it's nested within NavigationContainer?

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity, can you provide your RootNavigation file code?

But I think that your problem is that you don't have the "TrackListFlow" component in the "App" function return.
Your "App" function should be like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginFlow" >
        <Stack.Screen name="LoginFlow" component={LoginFlow}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="MainFlow" component={MainFlow} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TrackListFlow" component={TrackListFlow} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Try this code and give me your feedback :).

Comment: Thanks for replying, and good suggestion, but alas it gave the same error message. The only other thing that works is when I put the specific screen in the main navigator ie instead of TrackListFlow, just the individual TrackList screen. I kinda wanted to keep these navigators separate though and don't understand why I can't navigate to screens within the separate flows as long as they are under the main navigation container :S

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think I know how to solve your problem. You have to navigate to a nested navigator. Put the function in your RootNavigation file: ```javascript export function navigateNestedNavigator(name, params, screenName) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, 
    {
      screen:screenName,
      params
    }
    );
}``` You have to navigate to the "navigator" first and then navigate to the screen component,  where "name" param will be "TrackListFlow" and screenName will be  "TrackList", you got it? Waiting for your feedback :).